# how to dump mysql schema without keys and without constraint ? and keep all of them to alter afterwards

Tags: mysql, restore, foreign-key, mysqldump, amazon-rds

i am using ubuntu 16.04 and want to dump large schema with hounded of tables from AWS rds, remove all keys and foreign key , load data and then add back the keys , is there any automatic tool that does this? or any well known script for this ? i am currently using mysqldump https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html with this command :

```
mysqldump --skip-triggers --compact --no-create-info --single-transaction --quick --max_allowed_packet 1G  -h host_name.rds.amazonaws.com -u <user> -P 3306 -p<pwd> <schema> {table_name}> /mnt/tables_just_data/{table_name}.sql
```

Comment: I wonder why? mysqldump already creates statements that disable foreign key checks and indexes during loading.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/mysqldump-data-only) might be of use!

Comment: @tombom the `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS` statements emitted by mysqldump are [applicable only to MyISAM tables.  InnoDB ignores them.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-index)  Disabling foreign key checks does prevent FK constraint validation, but the indexes are still built as the rows are inserted.

Comment: You are write disable keys are only for myisam tables I am using innoDB

Comment: Please explain what your ultimate goal is; there may be a different way to do it.

Comment: ultimate foal - create dump for schema only without keys (just primary keys) so that  i could restore all the data on a fast way and then alter the tables and add the keys